# Craft CMS: action input module controller results in 404

Tags: php, twig, craftcms

I'm making a custom contact form in Craft CMS with a module. The goal is to view all submitted forms in the dashboard and have the possibility to mail after submissions. Submitting the form results in a HTTP 404 – Not Found error.

I made the module, controller and action needed for this. I configured the module in app.php of the config folder and added it to psr-4 in composer.json to autoload it. I know namespacing and routing is a common issue, so I tried a lot of possible combinations.

This is what the folder structure looks like:

```
modules/
├─ submissions/
    ├─ Module.php
    ├─ Controllers/
        ├─ defaultController.php
```

The action input of the form looks like this:

```
{{ actionInput('submissions/default/send-submission') }}
```

The module looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace submissions;

use Craft;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Define a custom alias named after the namespace
        Craft::setAlias('@submissions', __DIR__);

        // Set the controllerNamespace based on whether this is a console or web request
        if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\submissions\\console\\controllers';
        } else {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\submissions\\controllers';
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace modules\submissions\controllers;

use Craft;

class defaultController extends Controller
{

    protected $allowAnonymous = [
        'action' => self::ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LIVE | self::ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_OFFLINE,
    ];

    public function actionSendSubmission() 
    {
        echo "test";
    }    
}
```

Using an actionUrl also results in the same error:

```
<a href="{{ actionUrl('submissions/default/send-submission') }}">link</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, Craft CMS has its own [dedicated SE site...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Did you sort this? hitting the same issue. I'm sure it's something v simple!

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to register and bootstrap the module as `submissions` in `/config/app.php`, if you haven’t already.

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/module-guide.html#update-the-application-config

```php
return [
    'id' => App::env('APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',
    'modules' => [
        'submissions' => [
            'class' => \modules\submissions\Module::class,
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['submissions'],
    // ...
];
```

Also, you need to tell Composer how to find your module’s classes by setting the `autoload` field in your project’s `composer.json` file.

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/module-guide.html#set-up-class-autoloading

```
{
  // ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "submissions\\": "modules/submissions/"
    }
  }
}
```

FYI asking this type of question over at https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/ next time will likely result in a quicker answer.